# LDAP Authentication with JWT Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

Currently, I am Using Spring Security with LDAP authentication. But I want to Create one Rest API which will do LDAP authentication and will then I will generate JWT token so for upcoming request I can valid JWT tokens.

Any suggestions to achieve this ?

Comment: See https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ for LDAP authentication. 
Then you should implement a secured REST endpoint (auth/login for example) which will generate a JWT token, and add a JWT filter on API requests to check that JWT